# Need to display &amp; as it is in jQuery dialog title, but it is getting converted to &

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to display `&amp;` as it is in Jquery dialog box's title bar but it is getting converted to `&`. So, the idea is to display the value as it is in dialog box title. it is working fine for everything but when I am using `&amp;` or `&apos;` then it is getting converted to `&` or `'` respectively. Below is my code:

```
var name = '&amp;'
$('#testdialog')
   .dialog(
       {
           title: name,
           autoOpen: false,
           width: 900,
           height: 400,
           scrollable: true,
           draggable: true,
           modal: true,
           resizable: false,
           open: function (event, ui) {
               jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
               callTest();
           },
           close: function (event, ui) {
               jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
               $('#testdialog').html('');
           },
           buttons: {
               Ok: function () {
                   $(this).dialog('close');
               }
           }
   });$('#testdialog').dialog('open');
```

I want to display the value of name variable as it is. I tried keeping the value in a div and used `$("#divID").html()` in title attribute but it did not work. Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your variable to the following and you should be good to go:

```
var name = '&amp;amp;'
```

For `&apos;` use:

```
var name = '&amp;apos;'
```

Comment: Don't forget these: `&lt;` `&gt;` `&quot;`.